# Trying to import vrml files to unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, vrml, wrl

I have the following files

[image: vrml files]

And I'm trying to somehow import them without losing the references to each other to unity.

I tried through Blender but I can only export one wrl file at a time (I could be wrong), and that causes it to lose the reference to the animation and materials.